# Why does the revocation sent to the OpenPGP keyservers not show up?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I have created a new OpenPGP key pair. So I wish to revoke the former, I have used.

Here's what I managed to do so far.

1. This way I found that my email's ID is 3C76732B:

   ```
   gpg --search [email address removed for crawlers not to get it from here]
   ```
2. I imported it as follows:

   ```
   gpg --recv-keys 3C76732B
   ```
3. I found my private key and imported is like this:

   ```
   gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import secret.gpg.key
   ```
4. As I still remember the password for it I created the revocation certificate:

   ```
   gpg --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke 3C76732B
   ```
5. I imported the revocation key as follows:

   ```
   gpg --import revoke.asc
   ```
6. Here I am unsure, if I did this step Ok. I sent the same key ID back to the server:

   ```
   gpg --send-keys 3C76732B
   ```
7. Despite this says that the key has been revoked,..

   ```
   gpg --edit-key 3C76732B
   ```
8. .. I can't verify it on http://keys.gnupg.net

Any further steps I should take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key server network does not consists of a single server, but a whole bunch of servers that synchronize through "gossipping". `keys.gnupg.net` actually points to `pool.sks-keyservers.net`, which again randomly serves IP addresses of key servers operated by individuals. This will take a while, expect some time between few minutes and multiple hours.

If the key shows up as revoked locally and you recently uploaded it, just wait for some time and check again. You could select multiple servers from the [SKS keyserver pool](https://sks-keyservers.net/status/) and upload the key directly to different of them to speed up the process, for example by running

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.erat.systems --send-keys 3C76732B
```

(`keyserver.erat.systems` is the one I'm running). You don't have to upload to all of them, probably synchronization would actually be faster than you selecting the servers manually. As already explained, uploading to one (or one of the pool addresses) is sufficient if you wait for some time.